# Odoo 10 - Export res.partner CSV/Excel, where is state_id field?

Tags: odoo-10, odoo

When exporting partners, I would like to export state_id field, but I can not find it as available export field. Why?

Odoo 10 community

Comment: The `state_id` field should be called *State* in the export wizard. Is the field *State* not available for you in the *Available fields* column?

Comment: Indeed it is, I did not see it at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Naglis told you, you should look for **State** in the exportation menu. If you are using other language, look for the translation of *State* in *Settings > Translations > Application Terms > Translated Terms*, and then go to the exportation menu again and find the term. You also can click on your user name at the top right corner of the screen and click on *Preferences*. Then, switch temporaly the language to English, go to the exportation menu and now you'll see **State**.